# Using of AsEnumarable for Dataset in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have declared a DataSet and dumped some values from SQL,
Now I am writing a Linq query to fetch some column values

```
DataSet tblWebsites = new DataSet();
var items = from row in tblWebsites.AsEnumerable() select row.Field<string>("Filepath");
```

Now I am receiving error below
'DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'DataSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can someone suggest why this error is triggered. DO I need to add any assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough? You cannot apply that for DataSet, but it is possible to apply the same for a DataTable. So you have to choose one DataTable either by index or by the table name before querying them. So use like this if you wanted to query the Datatable.

```
 var filePaths = tblWebsites.Tables[0]
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Filepath"));
```

Comment: If I use above query also I have same error which described in my question

Comment: 'DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Sai: include `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;` to your header

Comment: I am already using it but when I build I get error like The type or namespace name 'DataSetExtensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions

Answer (score 0):

A `DataSet` is a collection of `Tables` and `Tables` has rows not datasets. That being said you could select the values of the column name `Filepath` for the *first* DataTable in the DataSetrows as below:

```
var items = from row in tblWebsites.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() 
            select row.Field<string>("Filepath");
```

> Still I have the same error if I use above query also

You should add `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` as a reference to your project.
and at the top of your source file state the following:

```
using System.Data;
```

Comment: Still I have the same error if I use above query also

Comment: use System.Linq at top